# Query taking too much

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute updates while my condition returns results, the problem is that when i am testing the query it never finishes.
Here is the query;

```
While(select COUNT(*) from Agreement as agr where agr.Id in (
  select toa.Id from Agreement_TemporaryOnceAgreement as toa where toa.Executed =1)
and agr.EndingDate is null) > 0
begin
DECLARE @AgreementID int;
SET @AgreementID = 
(
select top 1 agr.id from Agreement as agr where agr.Id in (
  select toa.Id from Agreement_TemporaryOnceAgreement as toa where toa.Executed =1)
and agr.EndingDate is null
)
update Agreement SET EndingDate = (
  select tado.Date from TemporaryAgreementsDateOfExecution tado
    where tado.AgreementId = CAST(@AgreementID AS INT))
where Agreement.Id = CAST(@AgreementID AS INT);
end;
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop.  A single update query resembling this should get the job done.

```
update a
set EndingDate = tado.date
from Agreement a join TemporaryAgreementsDateOfExecution tado
on a.AgreementId = tado.AgreementId

join Agreement_TemporaryOnceAgreement toa
on a.Id = toa.id

where EndingDate is null
and toa.Executed = 1
```

There might be slight variations depending on the RDBMS you are using.